# How to properly save excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I have a problem when I'm trying to save and than read excel file in python. So this is my function:

```
import openpyxl
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
import pandas as pd

def write_excel():
  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('8de69ccb60047ce5.xlsx')
  sheet = wb.active

  sheet['D18'] = 3

  wb.save('8de69ccb60047ce5.xls')

  df1 = pd.read_excel('8de69ccb60047ce5.xls', sheet_name='Лист1', header=None, skiprows=1, usecols="H,I")
  print(df1)

  workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('8de69ccb60047ce5.xls')
  worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
  print(worksheet.cell(17, 8).value)
  print(worksheet.cell(18, 8).value)
```

I'm changing cell `D18`, saving file and than trying to read other cells that has formulas but I get nothing (also cell without formulas read correctly).
But if I open file manually and save it in Excel that lines of code read those cells correctly.

The problem is this line `wb.save('8de69ccb60047ce5.xls')`. It saves changes in file but it doesn't saves file correctly (I don't know how to discribe it). How can I read cell with formula after changing the file in python?

Answer (score 1):

Save a file as **sample_book.xlsx** with save function.

```
wb.save(filename = 'sample_book.xlsx')
```

For more info check out this link: https://www.soudegesu.com/en/post/python/create-excel-with-openpyxl/#save-file

Comment: Doesn't help. Still can't get value from cell with formula.